# Distributed search in SOLR without UUID

Tags: solr

I am supposed to perform a distributed search over already existing lucene indices. The problem with these are, they don't have an UUID at all. In fact there is no field that would uniquely identify a particular doc in a single core.

Now I try to perform a single core search (assume I am searching for logon), I get around 1500 results. The same thing when I perform s distributed search over two cores, I get hardly 6-8 results.

Why is this happening? Is it because of the absence of an unique document id, or is it due to something else? If it due to the lack of UUID, what is the workaround you would suggest(if at all something exists). If it is the later, where should the problem be?

Edit :

[Here](http://pastebin.com/s7JZCnU9) is my schema.xml. This is same in both the cores

Comment: you can't have a document in the Lucene index without an ID. There must be some unique identifier.

Comment: Lucene has an internal id. But for instance if I use 2 cores, the doc in core 1 also has an id 1, the doc in core 2 also has an id 2. It is a confusion in case of distributed search right?

Comment: can we see the schema definition? as you refer to your problem, it seems like there's a strict condition on the searcher that finds a common point in only few results. we need to know more

Comment: Dear Samuele, have added an edit to my question. Please check and revert back.

Comment: Ok! I found it. It is because I have set the unique field as WMTIME and is not redundant. Hence only less number of results turn up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's prolly not the lack of UUID, but if you want to know how to create one automatically check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey

```
 <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
 <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW"/>
```

Comment: But the problem with my use case is the lucene indexes are already written by some one else. If I add this to my solr's schema.xml will it work?

Comment: You would need to restart Solr and reindex at the very least.